# How to exclude more than one th child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to exclude last and second last child of th to apply some css property.Individually it come be done like

```
.List  thead tr th:not(:last-child){
  //Some Css properties 
 }
```

and same for second last child.Can it be combined using not operator in one css selector?

Comment: If you know how many there are, and you don't add/subtract elements with javascript, you can use `:nth-child()` in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS3 brings us the `:nth-last-child()` selector. To combine multiple `:not` items just add them to the end.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLY3H/)

```
li:not(:last-child):not(:nth-last-child(2)) {
    color:red;
}
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=not) this method may be only fully supported from IE9. I say may be because caniuse isn't specific enough. Personally, I don't go out of my way to support < IE9 anymore unless it's a requirement.

Comment: +1 - always forget about this one, probably because it only works in IE9+ ?

Comment: Damn you IE :P According to caniuse.com IE9 is the first version to "fully support" CSS3 selectors http://caniuse.com/#search=not

Comment: @Alexander I need to use -n+3 for it to affect the last two (on Chrome).

Comment: @Tyriar, Chrome here. Works as expected. I know you meant to *not* affect the last two

Answer (score 0):

```
.List thead tr th:nth-last-of-type(1) ,.List thead tr th:nth-last-of-type(2) {
/*Some Code*/
}
```

Try This